# SSH into a virtual IP

Tags: ssh, load-balancing, cluster

I am attempting to SSH into a virtual IP on a loadbalancer. I want to connect to this virtual host name and have it connect me to one of the virtual hosts. The problem is when I try to ssh to the virtual IP, one of the actual IPs respons (reseting my connection).

Is there a way to configure the network to allow an ssh connection to the virtual host-name and have it connect me to one of the hosts?

eg network:
    192.168.0.3 -- server-cluster01
     -       .4 -- server01
     -       .5 -- server02
     -       .6 -- management

Managment's host file contains the entry for the server-cluster01.

From managment box:

```
root@managment~: ssh server-cluster01
```

From the monitoring tools I get

```
192.168.0.6 -> syn 192.168.0.3
192.168.0.4 -> ack 192.168.0.6
192.168.0.6 -> rst 192.168.0.3
(repeat)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I can see is to use NAT. The solution is similar to the solution I use at home (technically PAT I think) with port forwarding. I am able to SSH into a public IP which then forwards my traffic to a private IP.

I wish there was another solution other than NAT, but I don't see one. I'll keep the question open for a bit in case someone can offer a new solution.

Comment: IPv6, of course. :)

Answer (score 0):

This handshake should look similarly wrong for *any* TCP connection to the cluster, not specifically for ssh. (And in fact the same problem should occur for udp). Can yuo confirm (by sniffing) that other (working) services continue the handshake with the virtual address or with one of the member addresses?

(Sorry, this should be a comment, but I can't)

Comment: I will check this out. Why does ICMP work then?

Comment: What ICMP works?

Comment: The solution is to use NATing, which we didn't think would be an option at the time.